# How to "Select-Object" on multiple multiple-valued properties?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to retrieve Google Calendar events and bulk-copy them into a SQL Server table.

```
$requestUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/.../events"
$calEvents = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"} -Uri $requestUri -Method Get -Body $Parameters -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"
$dt = $calEvents.items | Select-Object id, ????????? | Out-DataTable
...
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt)
```

So my question is what to put into ????? so I would be able to save for organizer-email, creator-email, start-date, end-date into the table.

`$calEvents.items` looks like this:

```
created     : 2017-08-28T07:18:19.000Z
updated     : 2017-08-29T16:41:00.441Z
summary     : Vacation
creator     : @{email=XXX@YYY.com; displayName=XXX}
organizer   : @{email=XXX@YYY.com}
start       : @{date=2018-03-26}
end         : @{date=2018-03-31}
...
```

So I want to retrieve only email and date elements from `@{}` multivalues.
Any idea how?
(I know I can expand only one property).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are most likely nested objects. You should be able to "flatten" your data by using [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
$dt = $calEvents.items |
      Select-Object id, @{n='creator';e={$_.creator.email}},
          @{n='organizer';e={$_.organizer.email}},
          @{n='start';e={$_.start.date}},
          @{n='end';e={$_.end.date}} |
      Out-DataTable
```

Comment: Thanx bro! That was it. I have another problem though, and that is the property "start" sometimes looking like this:
    start             : @{dateTime=2018-06-27T11:00:00+02:00}
and something looking like this:
    start       : @{date=2018-03-26}
So how can I distinct between dateTime and date, I mean to give them different column names, one for date, another one for datetime.

Comment: Actually, "start" as a column name is OK, but it should contain either date or datetime entity, depending on which one exists (it must be one of the two).

Comment: Solved it with: e={$_.start.datetime+$_.start.date}} . I'm not sure if it's the best practice though.

Comment: Best way would be to fix your input data at the source. If that's not possible simply use a condition: `e={if ($_.start.date) {$_.start.date} else {$_.start.datetime}}`.

Answer (score 0):

other method:

```
$dt = $calEvents.items | %{
[pscustomobject]@{
                    id=$_.id
                    organizer=$_.organizer.email
                    start=$_.start.date
                    end=$_.end.date
                 }


} | Out-DataTable
```